# How to pass the "page" element to a function with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer

I’m trying check if elements are available on a page from within a function, if the element is on the page, good, continue with the code, if not, log the error.

Using the [try puppeteer page](https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/), here is what I tried:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

const check = element => {
  try {
    await page.waitFor(element, {timeout: 1000});
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("error : ", e)
    await browser.close();
  }
}

await page.goto('https://www.example.com/');
check("#something");

console.log("done")
await browser.close();
```

I get `Error running your code. SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. I debugged a bit and it seems that `page` within the `check` function is the unexpected identifier. So I tried to pass it in with force like this:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

const check = (element, page) => {
  try {
    await page.waitFor(element, {timeout: 1000});
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("error : ", e)
    await browser.close();
  }
}

await page.goto('https://www.example.com/');
check("#something", page);

console.log("done")
await browser.close();
```

but I get the same `Error running your code. SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this variant to check if the element is in the page or not.

```
if (await page.$(selector) !== null) console.log('found');
else console.log('not found');
```

Now back to your code, it's throwing error because of this function is not `async`,

```
    const check = async element => { // <-- make it async
      try {
        await page.waitFor(element, {timeout: 1000});
      } catch(e) {
        console.log("error : ", e)
        await browser.close();
      }
    }
```

Anytime you call `await`, it must be inside an `async` function. You cannot call await everywhere. So your check function should be called like this,

```
await check("#something", page);
```

So altogether we can rewrite the code snippet this way, you can go ahead and try this one.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
const check = async(element, page) => (await page.$(element) !== null); // Make it async, return true if the element is visible
await page.goto('https://www.example.com/');

// now lets check for the h1 element on example.com
const foundH1 = await check("h1", page);
console.log(`Element Found? : ${foundH1}`);

// now lets check for the h2 element on example.com
const foundH2 = await check("h2", page);
console.log(`Element Found? : ${foundH2}`);

await browser.close();
```

Also async functions will return promises, so you have to catch that promise or use another await. Read more about async await here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function
- https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await

Comment: Golden answer! Thank you!